# How translation, rotation and translation plus rotation of a body can be define particle by particle?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, linear-systems

Let use simple example, a uniform rod with center of mass (COM) at the center of rod. The rod is in free space there are no other forces acting on it.

1. If we apply single force acting on a particle at COM, it is a pure translation. What force experienced by the left particle from COM and the particle next to it and so on, also for the right side.
2. If we apply couple of forces acting on two particles not at COM, it is pure rotation. What force experienced by each particles also what force experienced particle at COM.
3. If we apply single force on a particle not at the COM, it produce translation + rotation. I know it reduce to single force and a couple at COM which produce translation plus rotation. I wanted to know what each particle experienced a force so as a whole we say single force not at COM can be reduce to single force and a couple as a gross.

According to newton's 3rd law, force on other particles are equal and opposite within the body so no force acting on other other particles then why particles accelerate or rotate as a single body if force is zero on every particle other than the point of application of force.

There must be something at which particles together acting as a body also the distribution of force. I don't know pls explain it is very confusing.

Comment: I think you might be asking whether it's possible to decompose the motion of a rigid body, into (a) translational motion of the center of mass and (b) rotational motion about the center of mass? If that is what you are asking, the answer is yes; see, eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics#Force-torque_equations

Comment: Hello @Andrew i don't wanted to know decompose of force. I wanted to know particle by particle. How force distribute or what force experienced each particle so as whole we see pure translation, pure rotation or translation plus rotation.

Comment: For a rigid body? Or in general?

Comment: For rigid body. You can use example of uniform rod as i asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the rod has mass $M$ and length $L$, and the density is uniform. Let's imagine breaking the rod into $N$ mass elements each of mass $m=M/N$ and length $\ell=L/N$. Then the equation of motion for the $i$-th mass element is
\begin{equation}
m \ddot{\vec{x}}_i = \vec{F}_{\rm external}^{(i)} + \vec{F}^{(i)}_{\rm constraint}
\end{equation}
where $F_{\rm external}^{(i)}$ represents any *external* forces applied directly to particle $i$, and $F_{\rm constraint}^{(i)}$ represents *internal* forces which are responsible for maintaining the shape of the rigid body. You can think of this as being a crude model of the electrostatic interactions that hold real objects together. At a deep level, there are no truly rigid bodies and there are no magic "constraint forces" that guarantee an object has a prescribed shape, but a rigid body is a reasonable approximation to make for many objects and it's easier to figure out what a rigid body will do than other kinds of extended objects.

In practice, the best way to find $\vec{F}_{\rm constraint}^{(i)}$ is to solve for the rotation of the rigid body by decomposing its motion into linear motion of the center of mass and rotational motion about the center of mass, then work out what the constraint forces must be so that every particle follows the necessary trajectory.

For example, consider pushing the rod on the left end with force $f$. We'll label the particles so the particle at the very left end of the rod is $x_1$, and the particles to the right of it are $x_2, x_3, \cdots$. Well, the *external force* on $x_1$ is $f$, while the external force on $x_2, x_3, \cdots$ is $0$. However, you know how the rod will move; the whole rod will move along the line of force, with an acceleration $f/M$. This means that every particle must accelerate with force $f/M$. This in turn means that every particle $x_2, x_3, \cdots$ experiences a net constraint force of $m f/M = f / N$. Meanwhile, the first particle must also experience a net force of $f/M$; since the force applied on $x_1$ is $f$, it must be that the constraint force is $-(N-1)f/N$.

The key point is that a rigid body is an *overdetermined system*. No matter how large $N$ is, there are only 6 degrees of freedom for a rigid body (the position of the center of mass, and the orientation of the body in space, which you can think of in terms of the Euler angles). So once you solve for the motion of those 6 degrees of freedom, the motion of all $N$ particles is completely fixed, and you can determine what internal forces the body must have in order to remain a rigid body.

You can do a similar analysis for any kind of rigid body motion, although in general it will be much more complicated. There are problems where calculating the internal/constraint forces is interesting; for example, you can determine if the stress at some point reaches a critical value where you would expect the material to crack.

You can also go beyond the rigid body approximation, by allowing the internal forces to depend on the relative positions of the particles, rather than assume the particles are always in a fixed relative position. The simplest version of this is the theory of [linear elasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity).

Comment: Hello , i can understand the linear motion. Pls explain translation plus rotation of rod in free space there are no fixed point in the rod it rotate about its center of mass. If force is applied to the left end particle of the rod perpendicular to the length of the rod. It will do translation plus rotation.

Comment: @123 You can do the analysis by breaking the motion into translation of the center of mass, and rotation about the center of mass. That's described in many books. Once you have that information, if you want to know what's going on at a particle-by-particle level, you can calculate all the constraint forces that would be needed to produce that motion by using the method in this answer (essentially solving $F_{external}+F_{constraint}=ma$ for $F_{constraint}$, since you know $F_{external}$, $m$ and $a$). It's conceptually the same as in the linear motion example, just more complicated.